# Playground: Use of unresolved identifier 'NSColor'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, swift-playground

I tried to play with playground in Xcode6-Beta4, and type the following:

```
import UIKit
let color = NSColor.blueColor()
```

and the error is:

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'NSColor'
```

Can someone explain why?

Comment: With UIKit, you should use UIColor: `let color = UIColor.blueColor()`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are developing for iOS and thus using `import UIKit` (as your code shows), then the appropriate color interface comes from `UIColor`.  As such:

[image]

For code meant to work in both iOS and OS X you can use:

```
#if os(macOS) || targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
import AppKit
typealias ColorType = NSColor
#elseif os(iOS)
import UIKit
typealias ColorType = UIColor
#endif

let color = ColorType.blackColor()
```

Answer (score 5):

`NSColor` is a class member of `AppKit`, not `UIKit`.

To use `NSColor`:

```
import Cocoa
```

Answer (score 4):

NSColor is a part of [AppKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/ObjC_classic/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001093) (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html_)

UIColor is part of [UIKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKit_Framework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006955) (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Either import [UIKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKit_Framework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006955) or replace `NSColor` with `UIColor`